# authorization has been denied for this request using JWT On Host Not on Local

Tags: api, authentication, owin, jwt

i implement JWT authentication using OWIN .
i set expire date after month , and It work fine On localhost When publish on Godaddy host , Token work for short time (minutes  ) after that I need new token 
I do not know what the problem do i need any configuration on web.config ?
Please Help

Comment: I use your artical  to create token , can you help me? @taiseer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix it by genrate machine key and add it in web.config